# Segfault running OpenCV under Apache / WSGI with python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, wsgi

I've got a django app that uses OpenCV for image processing and I'm running into problems deploying it in production.  I can run the app just fine directly from python or using `manage.py runserver`.  But when I try to run it inside apache / wsgi, as soon as it gets to the line

```
import cv
```

it blows up with

```
[Thu Jan 27 01:13:16 2011] [notice] child pid 21348 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I don't know where to start debugging this.  Maybe recompile opencv with some different flagss?

FWIW, Python 2.6.5, OpenCV 2.2.0, Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes

Then go through:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues

where it further elaborates on what can cause the crashes.

Finally, you could investigate the point of the actual crash using:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB